# Docker compose running java and tomcat using docker file in windows container

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network, windows-container

Secnario: Trying to run JAVA and Tomcat using a docker compose file with dockerfile

Step 1: Created a Docker compose file

*version: '3'
services:
  tomcat:
     container_name: Tomcat_Java
     build:
        dockerfile: 
     ports:
       - "8080:8000"*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/feLtk.jpg

Step 2: Created a dockerfile for java + tomcat service
 *# SPECIFY THE CONTAINER IMAGE
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore*

## COPY THE APACHE TOMCAT INSTALLATION FILES INTO THE CONTAINER

ADD ./birdoncloud/setup c:/source

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "c:/source/jre.cmd;"]

## INSTALLING JAVA JDK

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "c:/source/jdk.cmd;"]

## COPYING TOMCAT FILES TO C drive

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "Copy-Item c:/source/tomcat -Destination c:/tomcat -Recurse;"]

## SETTING UP ENVIRONMENT PATH VARIABLES FOR JRE & JDK FOLDERS

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "c:/source/Environmentvariable.ps1;"]

## Installing Tomcat service

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "c:/source/tomcatservice.bat;"]

## Installing Elasticsearch  service

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "sc.exe config tomcat9 obj=LocalSystem start=auto;"] 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz3tZ.jpg

Step 3: running Docker-compose up

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUp0n.jpg

Request you please respond at the earliest

Comment: Paste raw text as text and not as images

Comment: version: '3'
services:
  tomcat:
     container_name: Tomcat_Java
     build:
        dockerfile: 
     ports:
       - "8080:8000"

Comment: FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

ADD ./birdoncloud/setup c:/source

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "c:/source/jre.cmd;"]

# INSTALLING JAVA JDK

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "c:/source/jdk.cmd;"]
# COPYING TOMCAT FILES TO C drive

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "Copy-Item c:/source/tomcat -Destination c:/tomcat -Recurse;"]


SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "c:/source/Environmentvariable.ps1;"]


# Installing Tomcat service
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "c:/source/tomcatservice.bat;"]